# ASp.net Radio Buttons list selected Index always Zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web

I have Radio Buttons  list with 4 items in it and one button object and I use this Code in vb.net in the code behind

```
   Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Session("k1") = RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex.ToString()
    Label1.Text = Session("k1").ToString()
End Sub
```

I want to get the the value of the select index of selected item when button clicked but it's always give me zero ??? 
Any one can help Thanks.

Comment: How do you populate the data to RadioButtonList?

Comment: Or post you aspx for RadioButton list.